# How to convert an object into array of values only [Typescript]

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying some features of Angular. I'm facing a problem with Object and Array. Let's say I've a custom component, `Filter`, and a service, `FilterService`.  Here's my code:

**filter.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FilterService } from '../services/sinsense-filter.service';

@Component({
    ...
})

export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {

  public appliedFilters: string[] = []

  constructor(public filterService: SisenseFilterService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    var obj = this.filterService.filtersApplied;

    var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { 
        return [Number(key), obj[key]];
        // return [obj[key];
    }); 

    // this.appliedFilters=result;
    // console.log(this.appliedFilters);
    // console.log(typeof(result));

  }
}
```

**Note:** I've commented out the solutions that I tried

and here's the service code **filter-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FilterService {
    filtersApplied: object;
    constructor() {
        this.filtersApplied = new Object();
        
        this.filtersApplied={
            property1: "value1",
            property2: "value2",
            property3: "value3"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm following an article on GeeksForGeeks:
[How to convert an Object {} to an Array [] of key-value pairs in JavaScript?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-an-object-to-an-array-of-key-value-pairs-in-javascript/)

but I'm getting compatibility error:

> Type 'any[][]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
>
> Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Please correct me. I don't want keys in my final array. I just want `appliedFilters` to be:

> ["value1", "value2", "value3"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.map` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) takes the function which should return the value made from each element in the given array in order to create new array of the same length. So in your code you need to return just the desired value via `obj[key]` instead of returning unnecessary array for each item.

```
....
var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { 
    return obj[key] // return just the value!
});
```

Comment: Oh. I was unable to think that way. So stupid of me. :-(

Comment: Give me 1 min please. I'll quickly run some unit test cases.

Comment: Sir, this is working perfectly. But when I do `console.log(typeof(this.appliedFilters));` why it is still showing me `object`? I'm expecting an array.

Comment: An array is an object.